# Url handling issue in nginx

Tags: nginx

we want url handling like this.

If `/admin` then open the page for login (`/admin/dev/views/landing/index.html`) .

And if Url is `/admin/users` then open the page (`/admin/dev/views/adminAccount/index.html`) 
,the url is anything `/admin/*` i.e. `/admin/users`,`/admin/cameras` etc anything after /admin/* we have to open this file (`/admin/dev/views/adminAccount/index.html`) we handle routing using Angularjs in `/admin/dev/views/adminAccount/index.html` , so if any thing after /admin/* we wants to open `/admin/dev/views/adminAccount/index.html`

And we do this but it is not working

```
location /admin {
        index /admin/dev/views/landing/index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/dev/views/login/index.html;
    }

    location /admin/* {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/dev/views/adminAccount/index.html;
    }
```

But it does not work  when I am try `http://localhost:8585/admin/user-list` login page i.e. (`/admin/dev/views/login/index.html`) opens

Comment: You say it's not working but you don't say what happens.

Comment: nothing happens , same login page open .. Okk I edit my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an exact match you need to use "="

Also that wild card didn't work when I tried it, but just using a normal match without "=" did. Also I don't think you need that index statement or the checks for existing files under the exact url match.

```
# this matches only /admin
location = /admin {
    try_files $uri /admin/dev/views/login/index.html;
}

# this matches anything under /admin/*
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/dev/views/adminAccount/index.html;
}
```

Comment: this fails to start the nginx server

Comment: Ohh $uri $uri/ is missing , but after make change /admin didnot work , /admin/users work fine

Comment: can you please provide link that helps me

Comment: I just edited - try it this way. I was able to test on my own server earlier and it worked fine. $uri and $uri/ mean see if a file exists that matches $uri, then see if a directory exists that matches $uri/ - you don't really want either of those,